# How to Reload Magento2 Site after SSL Certificate Instalation

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, ssl-certificate

I discovered that our magento site SSL certificate expired before we were able to renew it causing the homepage to be defaced and leaving visitors with the option to have to manually bypass the SSL expiry warning on the homepage.

Now that that the certificate is renewed, the SSL authority issued a new certificate meaning that we have to remove the previously installed SSL certificate on the centos server and install the newly generated one.

After the removal and installation of the new certificate on the server, does magento automatically after redeploying and recompiling via SSH.??

Or which operations/commands are required for magento to recognise the newly installed SSL certificate??

Thanks

Samuelson

Comment: You no need to do anything since already you are using an URL with SSL in web base URL.

Answer (score 0):

if you updated your SSL cert, it will work as usual.
magento already have https configured, it is web browsers that needs to reload your new https connection.